# group php foreach loop (Closed)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count

How can i group php foreach?i'v already tried 5 days,but still can't get it work
i don't know php foreach how it works, but I'm learning it,
Thanks to everyone's advice

original php:

```
<?php if(isset($this->leading) && count($this->leading)): ?>
        <?php foreach($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>
            <?php

                $this->item=$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if(isset($this->primary) && count($this->primary)): ?>
        <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): ?>
            <?php

                $this->item=$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if(isset($this->secondary) && count($this->secondary)): ?>
        <?php foreach($this->secondary as $key=>$item): ?>          
            <?php

                $this->item=$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

i tried

```
<?php if(isset($this->leading) && count($this->leading)) && (isset($this->primary) && count($this->primary)) && (isset($this->secondary) && count($this->secondary)): ?>
    <!-- Leading items -->
        <?php foreach (array($this->leading, $this->primary, $this->secondary) as $key=>$item)          ($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>
            <?php
                // Load category_item.php by default
                $this->item=$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

but not work

As always, your assistance is appreciated!

Thanks!every one:)

Thanks,Steven!

Comment: Why are you using `<?php ?>` on each line?

Comment: I dont understand why are you messing up the code with <?php ?> tag in every line when you can write all the code within single tag?

Comment: You really like having `<?php _foo_ _bar_ ?>` in every line of code, don't you? But it's really odd. Please reformat it - it's hard to read.

Comment: And what the hell are you trying to do ? Those 3 ´foreach´ seems to do differents stuff each, so I think they should all be kept...

Comment: sorry, I don't know php foreach how it works, but I'm learning it

Comment: Hi,Bartdude so impossible to put it all together ?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this..?

```
<?php

$arr = array();
$arr[] = $this->leading;
$arr[] = $this->primary;
$arr[] = $this->secondary;

foreach($arr as $v) {    
    if(is_array($v) && (count($v) > 0)) {
        foreach($v as $item) {
            $this->item=$item;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function like:

```
function foobar ($tmp) {
    if(isset($tmp) && count($tmp)) { 
        foreach ($tmp as $key => $item) {
            // Load category_item.php by default
            $this->item = $item;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        }
    }   
}
```

and call it with your data:

```
foobar($this->leading);
foobar($this->primary);
foobar($this->secondary);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this is to first build a list containing all the items you need, and then use just one foreach to cycle through that list.

I'd also recommend some consistancy in whether the three variables (leading, primary, secondary) are defined. If you can guarantee that they're set and are arrays - even if they're empty arrays, it can make your code as simple as this:

```
<?php
$items = array_merge($this->leading, $this->primary, $this->secondary);
foreach ($items as $Item) {
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->loadTemplate('item');
}
?>
```

If you really don't know whether the variables are set, and you can't refactor your code elsewhere to change this, you could do this instead:

```
<?php
$items = array();
if (isset($this->leading)) $items = array_merge($items, $this->leading);
if (isset($this->primary)) $items = array_merge($items, $this->primary);
if (isset($this->secondary)) $items = array_merge($items, $this->secondary);
foreach ($items as $Item) {
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->loadTemplate('item');
}
?>
```